# Is this possible? .classname ,div,td {}

Tags: html, css, tags

Is it possible to assign multitags to a class like this? Any similar way of doing this?

```
.classname td, div {
css code
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to style divs or tds in a .classname, you need:

```
.classname td, .classname div {...}
```

Your code styles a td in your .classname and *all* divs.

Answer (score 2):

Technically @NCode and @Artefacto answered your question.  So, select whichever of their answers you'd prefer.  I just wanted to clear up any confusion.

The first example has a narrow scope.  Only Hello World will be given the color value red.

```
td.classname, div.classname { color: red; }

<table>
<tr>
<td class="classname">Hello World</td>
<td>Goodbye World</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div class="classname">Hello World</div>
<div>Goodbye World</div>
```

The second example has a wide scope.  Both Hello World and Goodbye World will be given the color value red.

```
.classname td, .classname div { color: red;}

<section class="classname">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Hello World</td>
<td>Goodby World</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div>Hello World</div>
<div>Goodbye World</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

That selections all `td` elements that are descendants of some element with class `classname`, PLUS all the divs. If you want all `td` and `div` elements with class `classname`, you must do:

```
td.classname, div.classname {
    /* foo */
}
```